# How can I turn one of these links into a dropdown menu?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently making a website using a Tumblr theme. I want one of my links (Merchandise) to open a dropdown menu for different options. Is there a way to do this without switching the entire navigation to li elements? I can style it all after, I just have no idea how to do this without ruining the entire theme.
Thanks in advance.

```css
#pages {
  float: right;
}
#pages a {
  float: right;
  color: black;
  margin: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 10px;
}
#pages a:hover {
  color: #d95e40;
}
```

```html
<div id="pages" class="desktop">
  <a href="/contact" title="Contact"><h2 class="page">Contact</h2></a>
  <a href="http://ryanblack.net" target="_blank"><h2 class="page">Merchandise</h2></a>
  <a href="/videos" title="Videos"><h2 class="page">Videos</h2></a>
  <a href="/lyrics" title="Lyrics"><h2 class="page">Lyrics</h2></a>
  <a href="/releases" title="Releases"><h2 class="page">Releases</h2></a>
  <a href="/shows" title="Shows"><h2 class="page">Shows</h2></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful site that has made a plugin just for this sort of situation
http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

On there you'll see the option to add a dropdown to an `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="#" data-jq-dropdown="#jq-dropdown-1">Merchandise</a>
```

Your actual dropdown list would then reside in the jq-dropdown-1 div. Or whatever you'd like to name it.

```
<div id="jq-dropdown-1" class="jq-dropdown jq-dropdown-tip">
<ul class="jq-dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="jq-dropdown-divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

The plugin Does the rest, giving you a simple solution to `<a>` tag dropdowns after simply linking to the required scripts

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.dropdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
```

Which can be found on the GitHub page here >> https://github.com/claviska/jquery-dropdown